# Number of substrings in a string: n-squared or exponential

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

How many subtrings are there in a string in general?

```
Why does string x [1:n] have O(n^2) subtrings according to the lecture 21 Dynamic Programming III of        
6.006 from MIT? 
Why it is not O(2^n)?
```

Here is a link [http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/MIT6_006F11_lec21.pdf]

Comment: This isn't really appropriate here, for a few reasons. For one, if I'm reading this properly, it references something to which we don't have access. For two, we aren't homework-doing machines. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255615/1270504).

Comment: A substring is completely defined by two parameters, such as start and length, in the range [1:n], so there are no more than n^2 possibilities. A general, non-contiguous, subset needs n true-false decisions to specify it, so there are 2^n possibilities.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about combinatorics.

Comment: This is not for homework. I learned materials by myself, but I got confused in some details in the lecture notes. I give the link to the lecture notes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about combinatorics

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply a **substring** is defined by two parameters `[i,j]` which are start index and end index for **substring** in the original string . Now `0<=i,j<=n` as indices should be within the string, Total values `i&j` each can have are n so all combinations of `[i,j]` would be n*(n+1)/2 which is `O(n^2)`

Comment: Also, i <  j so this isn't accurate. And 0,0 the trivial case doesn't count.

Comment: Gi0rgi0s I know , this was just a order analysis so no need to go into details

Answer (score 53):

Take a string length n=4, say: "ABCD"

The sub-strings of the above are (by length):

- 1 character: A,B,C,D   (**4** sub-strings)
- 2 character: AB,BC,CD, (**3** sub-strings)
- 3 character: ABC,BCD   (**2** sub-strings)
- 4 character: ABCD      (**1** sub-string)

Totaling the numbers yields: 1+2+3+4 = **10**.

So, to generalize, the number of possible sub-strings is the sum of all integers from 1 to n.

This sum is calculated using the formula **(n^2 + n) / 2** (see here: [Sum of Consecutive Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100897/sum-of-consecutive-numbers))

So the efficiency is of the **n^2** order of magnitude.

Comment: This is a far superior answer than the accepted answer. This is the one that should have been accepted!

Comment: Looking back at this, I wonder...is the full string a substring? if not, then subtract one from the answer.

Comment: Or add 1 for the empty string `""`

Answer (score 7):

Given a string of n elements,

If you start with 1st element, you can form n strings

If you start with 2nd element, you can form n-1 strings
.... so on...

For example, take 1234

1,12,123,1234

2,23,234

3,34

4

As you can see, the total is `n + (n-1) + (n-2) ...1` i.e. **sum of n elements** which is **`n(n+1)/2`**

Comment: This answer adds nothing to the answers from years ago.

Answer (score 3):

you might have been confused with the number of subsets of a set but it is seemingly important here that these are the substrings which have fixed pattern and the value that you think 2^n, that will be the number of subsequences of the given string.

Answer (score -3):

There are as many substrings as you want to get. Beginning and ending at an index.

```
string.Substring(0, 10); // untill 10th character, and so on
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

If you're trying to get string using `foreach` you'll get each string splitted at the space character. So, space character would specify the number of strings inside a string.

```
string strngs = "Love for all, Hatred for none!";

foreach (string strng in strngs) {
   Console.WriteLine(strng);
}

// (Expected) Output
// Love
// for
// all,
// Hatred
// for
// none!
```

Comment: Is any python function available?